# Problems when trying to persist an Entity

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I'm getting errors when trying to persist my entity class into Oracle database. Here is my Entity class

```
    package com.airline.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Passenger
 *
 */
@Entity

public class Passenger implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PASSENGER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="PASSENGER_SEQ",sequenceName="PASSENGER_SEQ1", allocationSize=1)
    private Integer id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private LocalDate dob;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FlightClass flightClass;

    ...
}
```

and also the class implementing AtributeConverter for LocalDate type

```
   package com.airline.converter;

    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.sql.Date;

    import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
    import javax.persistence.Converter;

    @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

        @Override
        public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
            return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));

        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
            return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
        }
    }
```

However when I try to persist it I'm getting this error:

```
> 

    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    Error Code: 942
    Call: INSERT INTO PASSENGER (ID, DOB, FIRSTNAME, FLIGHTCLASS, GENDER, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [6 parameters bound]
    Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.airline.models.Passenger@2441be63)
```

I'm using Eclipse Link as persistence unit.
Persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="airline">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/airline</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.airline.models.Passenger</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What can be done to persist the entity class.

Regards,

Comment: You don't post your persistence.xml, don't tell us whether the table `PASSENGER` is in the database, and don't tell us how you're trying to persist the entity. You just write you have a problem. How do you think should we know what problem you have?

Comment: I have added the persistence.xml to my post. I think the issue is with EclipseLink schema generation. I know that Eclipse Link will create for example a table to store references to sequences (sequence name and sequence counter).

Comment: Passenger table is not on the database and I'm trying to persist the entity via a session bean with is called via CDI from a servlet.

Comment: the "drop-and-create-tables" does not seem to work.

Comment: have you tried adding `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>` to your persistence.xml?

Comment: also, try `<property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="output.log"/>` and `<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>` and check if there are any errors in the log file. Maybe you don't have for example permissions to create the table.

Comment: Thank you all very much :-) It was a problem of missing rights to create and drop tables on database for the user.

Comment: @SocketM Please consider cleaning up this question, as the problem arose from misconfiguration of the surrounding environment.